# looping HttpWebRequest hangs the program until it is finished

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

My code is working but my only problem is that the entire program freezes while it is looping and the freeze only stops when the loop is done, is there any way to get rid of this freezing? i want to see it display from 1 to 21 but instead it freezes and only displays number 21 right away.

Here is my code. Should i change something so that it would tweak its performance? 
Thanks in advance

```
  Dim x As Integer = 0
    Do
        Dim POST As String = "authenticity_token=weZnH8V68yQSnQh91UtDZyatys%2FXtPQGN2vooyW4opY%3D&email%5Bto_address%5D=intes2010%40gmail.com&email%5Bfrom_name%5D=Test&email%5Bfrom_address%5D=test%40email.com&email%5Bnote%5D=today+is+a+big+success&email%5Bcopy_yourself%5D=0&id=house-of-pies-466226000"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        request = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/house-of-pies-466226000/send_email?lid=1000083727260"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = POST.Length
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.CookieContainer = tempCookies

        Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST)
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)
        Dim postreader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreader.ReadToEnd
        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
        response.Close()

        x = x + 1
        Label1.Text = x
    Loop While (x <= 20)
```

Comment: Is this process in a backgroundworker?

Comment: never tried using backgroundworker. i am kinda new to VB.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this in a backgroundworker.

Thats why your main UI freezes because its waiting for your code to finish. When you have a process that takes time to process, the only way to keep a responsive UI is to use multithreading.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx - This one shows the basic on how to use the background worker.

Keep in mind you can only change the value of a textbox for instance from the progresschanged event.

What you can do is that have a button, that starts the backgroundworker, and then you put the code above in the Dowork event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    Try
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Do
            Dim POST As String = "authenticity_token=weZnH8V68yQSnQh91UtDZyatys%2FXtPQGN2vooyW4opY%3D&email%5Bto_address%5D=intes2010%40gmail.com&email%5Bfrom_name%5D=Test&email%5Bfrom_address%5D=test%40email.com&email%5Bnote%5D=today+is+a+big+success&email%5Bcopy_yourself%5D=0&id=house-of-pies-466226000"
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse
            Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
            request = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/house-of-pies-466226000/send_email?lid=1000083727260"), HttpWebRequest)
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.ContentLength = POST.Length
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.KeepAlive = True
            request.CookieContainer = tempCookies

            Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST)
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
            requestStream.Close()

            response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)
            Dim postreader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

            Dim thepage As String = postreader.ReadToEnd
            e.Result = CType(thepage, String)
            response.Close()

            x = x + 1
            worker.ReportProgress(x)
        Loop While (x <= 20)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Try
        Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_Completed(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Try
        RichTextBox1.Text = e.Result.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Depeinding on how you want the data in richtextbox to be displayed, this needs also to be handeld in either progresschanged or the completed event.

Comment: it gives me an error saying BackgroundWorker1 is not declared.
i tried declaring it by

Dim BackgroundWorker1 As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

but it gives me an error saying type 'BackgroundWorker' is not defined

Comment: i solved it by importing "Imports System.ComponentModel"

but now it is giving me an error saying:
"Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."

it was pointing out these three lines:

Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Drag a backgroundworker component from the toolbox into your solution, this will created the handlers for the different events

Comment: Or, you can add handlers in your code yourself also......like this for instance..............AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_DoWork
AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged 
AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_Completed

Comment: yes i am using Visual Studio 2012. my program was able to run now without errors but it seems like it won't execute my code under BackgroundWorker1_DoWork.

Comment: yes i have placed a messagebox under the catch and it displays.
it directly goes into the catch everytime.

Comment: so that means a error occure. what does the error say? msgBox(ex.message)

Comment: "This backgroundworker states that it doesn't report progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report progress"

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will read more on about Background Worker. it seems to be a very useful tool for my program. Thanks alot for introducing me to this, now i have some reading and discovering to do.

i have been reading codes since morning, it's almost dawn here. i need some rest. Thanks for the time it was worth it.

Comment: You need to set ReportProgress to true. CLick the backgroundwoker and look in properties and change the reportprogress to true

Comment: Happy i could help! Yes, when building software using multithreading is very efficient and can perform multiple tasks for you!